# How to refactor directive code in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am coming from `.Net` world so I may be missing something obvious in `javascript` world in `angularjs`. I am writing few directives and they all have same kind of code where I need to setup same attributes.

Is it possible to create a function and use that function inside the link function of angular?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ofcourse, this is not something hard to do with javascript.

Here is some example code that does that.

```
(function(){
    function commonCode(){
        //common code goes here.
    }

    var app = angular.module("app");

    app.directive("first",function(){
        return function(scope,element,attrs){
            commonCode();
        }
    });


    app.directive("second",function(){
        return function(scope,element,attrs){
            commonCode();
        }
    });

    app.directive("third",function(){
        return function(scope,element,attrs){
            commonCode();
        }
    });

})();
```

And its even easier to do it with Angularjs.

If this common code is extremely generic, then you could refactor out this `commonCode` into a `service` and `inject` it into all your `directives`.